# Link Error: Unresolved External Symbol when creating object from Referenced file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have one solution with two projects: Project A and Project B.  I am referencing Project A from Project B (Project B is a test project for Project A).  When I try to create an object in project B from a class in Project A, I recieve linking errors.

**Example Code:**

```
//SampleClass.h, In Project A
#include <string.h>

class CSampleClass
{
public:
    CSampleClass(std::wstring arg1, int arg2);
    ~CSampleClass();
}

//Test.h, in Project B

class CTest
{
public:
    CTest(void);
    ~CTest(void);
    bool Run(void);
}


//Test.cpp, in Project B
#include "SampleClass.h"

CTest::CTest(void)
{
}

CTest::~CTest(void)
{
}

bool CTest::Run(void)
{
    CSampleClass sample; <--------- This line makes the error happen
}

//B.cpp, in Project B
#include "Test.h"

int main(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])
{
    CTest test;
    test.Run();
}
```

**Errors thrown during build:**

```
Error   3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   C:\Users\me\Project\Debug\ProjectB.exe  1   1 ProjectB
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CSampleClass::CSampleClass(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >,int)" (??0CSampleClass@@QAE@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@W4int) referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall CTest::Run(void)" (?Run@CTest@@UAE_NXZ)   C:\Users\me\ProjectB\Test.obj   ProjectB
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall CSampleClass::~CSampleClass(void)" (??1CSampleClass@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall CTest::Run(void)" (?Run@CTest@@UAE_NXZ)  C:\Users\me\Project\ProjectB\Test.obj   Project B
```

**Additional Info:**

I am referencing Project A from Project B like so: [image]

To include files from Project A in Project B I added Project A's source directory to Project B's Property pages under `Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Additional Include Directories`

The directory structure of the projects is like so:

```
\Projects\
--Debug\
----ProjectAOutput.* //.obj;.pdb;.sbr;.exe; etcetera
--ProjectB\
----Debug\
------ProjectBOutput.*//.obj;.pdb;.sbr;.exe; etcetera
----ProjectBSourceFiles.*
----ProjectBVisualStudioProjectFiles.*
--ProjectASourceFiles.*//.h;.cpp;
--ProjectAVisualStudioProjectFiles.*
```

**Question:**

I suspect that like I had to add the source directory of Project A to the "Additional Includes" section of Project B's properties, I also have to add the directory containing the build output of project A to project B's properties. I have been unable to find this however.

Does anyone know what has to be done to be able to use the classes from one Project in another?

Comment: Is `Project B` a DLL or an EXE?

Comment: @Wimmel Both projects build exe's

Comment: Then I think it will not be possible. Either you have to add `SampleClass.cpp` to project A, or you have to create a DLL (or static library) containing the shared code. You can link against the dll from both project A and project B.

Comment: @Wimmel does it matter that Project A is an MFC project?  In other words, can I build a DLL from an MFC project?

Comment: Yes, see for example [Creating an MFC DLL Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd5f0z40.aspx). I would not recommend trying to convert an existing project into a dll project. Just create a new project, and add the existing source files to it.

Comment: @Wimmel I don't want duplicate source code though, won't that put me in the same boat I'm in now where I will then have to reference the source code from Project A in the MFCDLL Project?

Comment: No, you should not duplicate source code. First of all you can add a single file to multiple projects when you choose "add as link". That way the file will not be copied into the second project. But if you use a dll, you add source files just to the dll, so you can remove then from the other project. When you create a dll, an import library (.lib file) will also be created. you will use that to reference from the other projects to the dll. If you put both exe files and the dll in one directory, there is no duplication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63246/discussion-between-mdw7326-and-wimmel).